# putting Button as TableRowColumn in material-ui Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Need help with putting button as TableRowColumn in material-ui Table !!
I need to make an approval system to either approve or reject a user's request.
I tried doing so in a tabular form. I wanted to add two buttons "Approved" and "Rejected" in a TableRowColumn as given by material UI !!

THe code here is :

```
const usersToRequest = [
{ name: 'Rahul', phone: '1234567890', from: 'sunday', to: 'saturday', roomType: 'Single Room' },
{ name: 'Hari', phone: '9876554423', from: 'monday', to: 'sunday', roomType: 'Double Room' },
{ name: 'Rohit', phone: '0909090987', from: 'tuesday', to: 'monday', roomType: 'Twin Room' },
{ name: 'Rohit', phone: '0909090987', from: 'tuesday', to: 'monday', roomType: 'Twin Room' },
{ name: 'Rohit', phone: '0909090987', from: 'tuesday', to: 'monday', roomType: 'Twin Room' },
{ name: 'Rohit', phone: '0909090987', from: 'tuesday', to: 'monday', roomType: 'Twin Room' },
{ name: 'Rohit', phone: '0909090987', from: 'tuesday', to: 'monday', roomType: 'Twin Room' },
{ name: 'Rohit', phone: '0909090987', from: 'tuesday', to: 'monday', roomType: 'Twin Room' },
];




<TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false} stripedRows>
{
usersToRequest.map((utr, i) => (
i < 4 ? <TableRow key={i}>
<TableRowColumn>{i + 1}</TableRowColumn>
<TableRowColumn>{utr.name}</TableRowColumn>
<TableRowColumn>{utr.phone}</TableRowColumn>
<TableRowColumn>{utr.roomType}</TableRowColumn>
<TableRowColumn>{utr.from}</TableRowColumn>
<TableRowColumn>{utr.to}</TableRowColumn>
<TableRowColumn>
{
<RaisedButton label="Approved" primary={true} onClick={console.log("!23")}/>
<RaisedButton label="Rejected" secondary={true} onClick={console.log("!23")}/>
}
</TableRowColumn>
</TableRow> : ''
))
}
</TableBody>
```

THe buttons I added here are not functioning as desired !!!!

Comment: When you say not functioning, please let us know what error do you see? Also, do you need to enclose the <RaisedButton> in curly braces? They are just custom components right?

Comment: Shrawan, Please let me know if the below solution worked for you and if yes, appreciat if you can upvote and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You're not binding event handlers properly:
Try this:

```
<RaisedButton label="Approved" primary={true} onClick={()=>{console.log("!23")}}/>
<RaisedButton label="Rejected" secondary={true} onClick={()=>{console.log("!23")}}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

RaisedButton is a custom component and you are passing"onClick" as a prop to it. Then you have to accept the prop in the child component and define the click function in the parent. Something like in this codesanbdbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/6lp8vkyrnz

```
  const handleClick = name => {
    console.log(name);
  };

  <TableCell>
       <RaisedButton click={() => handleClick(row.name)} />
 </TableCell>
```

*Raisedbutton*

```
function RaisedButton(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={props.click}>
      Default
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code with mui(material-ui new version)

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import RaisedButton from "./DemoChild.js";



let id = 0;
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  id += 1;
  return { id, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

function SimpleTable(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  const handleClick = (name) => {
    console.log(name);
  };
  return (
    <Paper>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Fat (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Carbs (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell numeric>Protein (g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Action</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            return (
              <TableRow key={row.id}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {row.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{row.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{row.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell numeric>{row.protein}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <RaisedButton click={() => handleClick(row.name)} />
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}

SimpleTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default SimpleTable;
```

and the Raised Button must be defined as follows:

```js
import React from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

function ContainedButtons(props) {
//   const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={props.click}>
      Default
    </Button>
  );
}

export default ContainedButtons;
```

And I have put that raised button in a different file in the path of ./DemoChild